# Make the column width dynamic in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the `shiny` app below Im trying to set the column width based on the `shiny` widget but I get   `column width must be between 1 and 12`

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "VMT-Mobility"),
  dashboardSidebar(
  
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(3,
             pickerInput(
               inputId = "cat",
               label = "Select categories",
               choices = c("1st","2nd"),
               selected="1st",
               multiple = F,
               
             )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
  
      column(uiOutput("n1"),box()),
      column(uiOutput("n2"),box())
      
      
      
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$n1<-renderUI({
    if(input$cat=="1st"){
      9
    }
    else{
      3
    }
  })
  output$n2<-renderUI({
    if(input$cat=="1st"){
      3
    }
    else{
      9
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you're passing a UI element into `column` when it expects a numeric value. You could try creating reactive values in the server to calculate the widths, and construct the columns in the server using those reactive values e.g.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "VMT-Mobility"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    fluidRow(
      
      column(3,
             pickerInput(
               inputId = "cat",
               label = "Select categories",
               choices = c("1st","2nd"),
               selected="1st",
               multiple = F,
               
             )
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("cols")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  n1 <- eventReactive(input$cat, {
    if(input$cat=="1st"){
      9
    }
    else{
      3
    }
  })
  
  n2<- eventReactive(input$cat, {
    if(input$cat=="1st"){
      3
    }
    else{
      9
    }
  })
  
  output$cols <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(width = n1(), box(width = 12)),
      column(width = n2(), box(width = 12))
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```